# The method signInWithEmailAndPassword() is Unresponsive - Firebase Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a small program that registers users through `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`, which works like a charm. However, when I try to `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`, the program is unresponsive to incorrect email/password, correct email/password, etc. and then it simply reloads the page. The only time the sign-in program responds is when it detects the email being badly formatted.

Note: the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` and the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` are used in different Javascript files. Also, the firebase is well connected and the authentication is enabled.

There are no error messages. My goal for after signing in is to be taken to another page (index.html).

Thank you!

Below is my code for this method!

```
const loginEmail = document.getElementById("loginEmail");
const loginPassword = document.getElementById("loginPassword");

function loginToSearch() {
    const email = loginEmail.value;
    const password = loginPassword.value;

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(function(firebaseUser) {
            // Success
            window.alert("LOGGED IN");
            window.location = "index.html";
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            window.alert(errorMessage);
        });
}
```

The code that calls this method:

```
<form class="main-form">
    <h4>Login:</h4>
    <br/>
    <div id="login_div" class="main-div">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="loginEmail">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="Email" id="loginEmail" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="loginPassword">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="Password" id="loginPassword" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="loginBtn" onclick="loginToSearch()">Login!</button>
</form>
```

Real time listener for AuthState:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        console.log("Logged In!");
        console.log(user);
    } else {
        console.log('Not Logged In!');
    }
});
```

Thank you so, so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issues with the Firebase code, but I **do** see an issue with your HTML code...

You have a `button` at the end of your `form`, that button click is causing the form to be submitted. This is what's causing your page to reload. To fix it, include the click event in the button's `onclick` handler:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="loginBtn" onclick="loginToSearch(e)">Login!</button>
```

and then in your javascript:

```
function loginToSearch(e) {
    e.preventDefault();   // <-- prevent whatever default behavior would occur
                          //     in this case, it prevents the form submission

    const email = loginEmail.value;
    const password = loginPassword.value;

    // etc...
```

I suspect that if you fix this, your signin code will work - actually, I think it's already working - just that your page reload is occurring before you get the chance to see it.

Comment: OH MY! THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR HELPING OUT !! IT WORKED !! Been trying to figure out the reason for a long time :))))

Comment: @TheMaestro Awesome, glad it was useful! If my answer was helpful, please click the outlined checkmark to the left of the answer. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question will be marked as "having an accepted answer". It helps anyone searching for similar topics in the future, and gives me credit for the effort I put in. :) Thanks!

Comment: Definitely ! Just did :D